# How to configure Kafka JDBC Source Connector with stored procedure?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am very new to Kafka, I'm doing a PoC (my first Kafka app) and was curious to know if anyone has come across or worked on a custom JDBC Source Connector that uses a stored procedure to export data from Oracle into Kafka?

I know this could be considered an open-ended question by the SO community but thanks for your patience and I'd appreciate any feedback.

Thank you!

**Some background:**

- I already have stored procedures in Oracle which are used by an existing Spring app to extract and load data in a new DB (for a new version of an existing enterprise application).
- The table structure in the new database is different than that of the old.
- The Spring app (which uses Spring JDBC and works with Stored Procedures, Row Mappers etc.) was developed as a PoC to check connectivity, integration and to load data in the new DB.
- Now that it works, we're trying to introduce Kafka that would actually store the data and **then** load it into the new DB. The JDBC Sink Connector would be developed later.
- I am looking for an example (using Java, Maven, Spring) that would help me in getting started towards building a custom connector. Most of the example/docs show *curl* examples which doesn't fit my existing app. I maybe missing something here.

Comment: Please provide a simplified form of the stored procedure. Are there OUT parameters or a cursor is returned to get the data? And above all, clarify who should **call the procedure**? Do you expect that **Kafka** will *poll* the procedure?

Comment: Ideally, I would prefer the existing app to execute the stored procedures and transform the result sets according to RowMappers. However, I'm not aware how its performance would compare to Kafka's _poll_ feature. Following is the stored procedure OUT parameter example: `declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("param_ref_cursor", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new CustomRowCallbackHandler(<params>)))`

Comment: @RGB314 Did you get a way to call SP from connector? Please answer so that it will be helpful for the community.

Comment: I did not proceed with this approach as it was made redundant due to change in the application architecture and the way data was to be streamed.

Answer (score 1):

There is way that we can call SP though source connector property - query: call sp here by creating temp table and insert data

Comment: Are you sure? Does Source connector supports DML and/or  DDL operations?

Comment: I have created #TempTables inside SP and inserted data.

Comment: I mean is that working? (creation of temp tables inside SP, which is getting used by connector)

Comment: yes, I am following this design for 2 years. no issues in production.

Comment: sorry for getting back on this but you use the query url to execute the operation and then use table for the source?

Comment: "query": "drop table if exists #temptable; create table #temptable (fields same as stored procedure result); insert into #temptable exec schema.storedprocedure; select * from #temptable"